# Base64 Canvas encode method limited in size

Tags: canvas, base64, limit, encode

I hope someone here can help.

The function below correctly creates base64 strings from the images on my website.

If I manually add a larger b64 value (generated from from a 164k image) it works fine.

```
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA..... etc
```

However, if I use this function on the same 164k image I only get "data:," as the output value.

Is the canvas limited to the DataURL size it can output? If so what would be a better method to encode images programatically?

Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function imageFetch(imgpath, imgname)               
{
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = imgpath + imgname;                                       

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');                      
    canvas.width = imageObj.width;                                      
    canvas.height = imageObj.height;                                    

    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');                        
    canvasContext.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   

    var lenImgName = imgname.length;                                    
    var imgType = imgname.substring(lenImgName-3,lenImgName);           

    if (imgType == "jpg")                                               
    {
        base64Data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');                        
    }
    if (imgType == "png")                                               
    {
        base64Data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');                     
    }
    return base64Data;                                                  
}
```

Comment: If the canvas height or width is 0, you'll get 'data:' back from toDataURL. Can you check what those values are when the function is run for that image?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by brodney you'll get this result if the width or height of the canvas is 0 which it is because you do not wait for the image to load before you set the canvas size to the image's width and height and those properties return 0 if the image is not fully loaded.